# How put search bar inside list of SplitButton

Tags: angular, frontend, primeng

[Please, if you need more information. Let me know on the comments below. Regars]

I need to put a search bar inside the content list of a SplitButton. I'm using SplitButton from.

As default, SplitButton shows a list of elements. I would like to know if I can put a search bar before the list.

[image: SplitButton Image]

PrimeNG: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/splitbutton

I read on PF documentation that exists a property `appendTo` and I think I can put a search bar inside list of split button with this property. But it's not works.

I would like to know if exists another way to put this search bar inside splitButton's list or how can I use `appendTo` do to this like the link below, on "Advanced" splitButton element.

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/splitButton.xhtml (Java's primefaces)

[image: Image SplitButton I need]

Comment: Why the re-post of your question? [Trying put an element in splitButton with list - PrimeNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60237606/trying-put-an-element-in-splitbutton-with-list-primeng). You didn't make this one any more clear than the last.

Comment: Hi @R.Richards. Thanks for reply. I created a new post because the last was blocked. I edited the last post, but it's continue blocked. So I did a new post with some new details. I going to edit this post e put more details. Thanks

Comment: @Elrold, I am don't think so, this is the right user experience. When you are giving an option to search from the list, why you are putting the option on the list? Why a user needs to get the search option on the second click. There is one extra click involved. I would suggest putting the search on top by default. and use some other control.